# Python input from stdin in online judges

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdin, raw-input

I am beginner in Competitive programming and getting started. Familiar with C and C++, but Python is what I am learning.I am facing difficulty in input in Python
Problem is like : For given number of test cases, for ech test case , you will be provided with a number N and another number K, in same line. After this line, there will be N integers in a single line. You just have to divide and sum up like given below (brackets are just to keep track)

```
1 #test cases
3 2 #N  #K
4 5 7 #N integers
```

Answer would be `sum : 7` that is 4/2 + 5/2 + 7/2 = 7 (int division)

I have written a simple Python 2.7 program to accept input and perform operation.

```
t = map(int,raw_input())
t = t[0]
while t>=0:
    count=0
    n,k = map(int,raw_input().split())
    candies = map(int,raw_input().split())
    for candy in candies:
        count += candy/k
    t -= 1
```

I am getting error :

```
vivek@Pavilion-dv6:~/Desktop$ python kids_love_candies.py <in.txt >out.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kids_love_candies.py", line 6, in <module>
    n,k = map(int,raw_input().split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Another [link](http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/learning-python-programming-and-data-structures/learning-python-programming-and-data-structures--tutorial-1-saying-hello-world-and-basic-inputoutput) suggests to read input using `sys.stdin.readline()` but I have no idea how to apply it to my problem.
Which one should I use and why?Which is the correct way to learn and use them?

Comment: I've executed the script you posted in python 2.7.9, and after removing the brackets, everything worked, print count shows 7. Have you checked the line endings of this file ? is this a linux or windows file ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu and file is created using sublime text, and text file. @CristianoAraujo

Comment: The link to online compiler, same program and different input raising same error. @CristianoAraujo http://ideone.com/iWY71C

Comment: @CristianoAraujo Got mistake. t>=0 should be t>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read one too many lines, your while condition should be `> 0`.  But this whole thing is more complicated than need be

```
t = int(raw_input()) # no need to map
for _ in range(t): # loop with range instead of manual counting
    # loop body
```

When I want to loop over lines from stdin, I generally use `sys.stdin` instead.  In that case you could ignore the count

```
raw_input() # ignore the size
for line in sys.stdin:
    n, k = (int(i) for i in line.split())
    count = sum(int(c) for c in raw_input.split()) / k
```

Comment: Yeah, there are certain things in this code, which can be better.Which way to read input is better?

Comment: I prefer this way when you're just reading everything from stdin. If you want to read one line or be interactive then use `raw_input()`. There are other ways.